# Internationalism, globalism, transnationalism, or …?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, phrase-requests

The reseach policy-making in this country is aimed at publication in international journals, rather than domestic journals. This ————— in research policy-making might improve the quality of research works but has some side-effects too.

I want a word or maybe phrase for the blank to mean an attitude that is not just internal or domestic. In research, it is about wanting the researchers of the coutnry to publish internationally. What to call that? Internationalism, globalism, internationalization, transnationalism, internationalist attitude in research policy-making, … ?

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of similar words, many of which are mentioned by the OP. However we can find differences in meaning and area of use.

**internationalism** "international character, principles, interests, or outlook; a policy of cooperation among nations" ([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/internationalism)). [Wikipedia has an article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalism_(politics)) on internationalism as a political philosophy, which refers to a belief in international institutions such as the United Nations. The term is also widely used in socialist history to refer to those who supported global socialism rather than putting national interest first ([Wikipedia: Internationalist–defencist schism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalist%E2%80%93defencist_schism)). But it is also used in the US military ("Internationalism", [The Oxford Essential Dictionary of the U.S. Military](https://www.oxfordreference.com/view/10.1093/oi/authority.20110803100007676)) and by the [George W Bush Institute](https://www.bushcenter.org/catalyst/leadership/the-case-for-american-internationalism.html) ("The Case for American Internationalism",
Jon Kyl and Joseph Lieberman, *The Catalyst*, Issue 1, 2016) and is not solely a left-wing thing, or a term restricted to party politics.

**globalism** "a national policy of treating the whole world as a proper sphere for political influence" ([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/globalism)). [Wikipedia's article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globalism) points to a problem with this word: it is frequently used by antisemites and other conspiracy theorists to refer to international Jewish conspiracies, with "globalist" used as codeword to talk about Jews.

**globalization** "the act or process of globalizing : the state of being globalized
*especially* : the development of an increasingly integrated global economy marked especially by free trade, free flow of capital, and the tapping of cheaper foreign labor markets" ([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/globalization)) As Merriam-Webster says and the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globalization) agrees, this is specifically associated with economic and political changes from the 18th century that have seen increased integration in the global economy and closer relationships between nations; it is sometimes used as a snarl-word by anti-capitalists to refer to global commerce as a powerful entity outside of political control by national institutions; it has not gathered the antisemitic overtones as "globalism", but its use as an insult may be associated with left-wing anti-capitalism or populist right-wing rhetoric.

**internationalization** "to make international; *also* : to place under international control" ([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/internationalization)). There are two main areas in which it is used, exemplified by two Wikipedia articles, [Internationalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalization) which is about corporations increasingly acting beyond national boundaries and is a concept that (according to Wikipedia) goes back to Adam Smith's *Wealth of Nations*, and [Internationalization and localization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalization_and_localization) which refers to adapting computer software and other products to different countries with different languages and writing systems. This term is primarily used with narrower meanings, and therefore isn't relevant to the OP's case.

**transnationalism** "extending or going beyond national boundaries transnational corporations" ([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/transnationalism)). This is perhaps less common, and Merriam-Webster suggests it is used of corporations, and refers to crossing national boundaries (e.g. a German company operating in France) rather than being truly world-wide.

Of these words, if you are wanting to emphasise an outlook that goes beyond national borders to promote cooperation and understanding, then **internationalism** is the best match. This word is free of the negative associations that a term such as globalism or globalization might carry.

Answer (score 0):

As it seems that the international level is preferred because of the benefits from reaching a more numerous and varied readership—that is thus on the whole better informed—, perhaps this level deserves to be considered as directing to a point thought and research, and therefore be viewed as a frame of reference.

> **frame of reference** a set of ideas or facts that a person accepts and that influences the person’s behavior, opinions, or decisions:
> • The report provided a common frame of reference for discussing public policy.
> • "The observer interprets what he sees in terms of his own cultural frame of reference.

- This *international frame of reference* in research policy-making might improve the quality of research works but has some side-effects too.

Answer (score -2):

***international mindedness***

> International mindedness is an overarching construct related to intercultural understanding, global engagement and multilingualism... International mindedness is a view of the world in which people see themselves connected to the global community and assume a sense of responsibility towards its members. ([inspiringinquiry.com](https://www.inspiringinquiry.com/learning-community/international-mindedness))

The term is used a lot in the context of international education; it might fit your context as well.